# Generate Runtime type based on propertyinfo[]

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have got a list of PropertyInfo, now i need to either populate a new object with these propertyinfos and there values or generic a type runtime containing these properties so i can create a new instance of the object based on my runtime created type.

I cannot create a new instance of an object based on an earlier type because i just filtered out my collection based properties (this is due to serialization of an object; long story).

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think [TypeBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will suit your needs.
On the bottom of the page you will see a clear example.
Also if you need to build methods use Expression Trees instead of ILGenerator.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few options:

- Use TypeBuilder to create a runtime type. Use DefineMethodOverride to implement the get/set methods of the properties and return the interface type (with the runtime implementation).
- Use one of the many Mock frameworks. They basically do the plumbing for you; the result is the same.